# Java Thread wont run unless i put Thread.sleep(1);

Tags: java

I have a piece of practice code that is supposed to accept `1010` as the code when a user enters the code on the keyboard. The thread that keeps checking if the code was entered right wont run unless i put a `Thread.sleep(1);` in the `run()`

I wanted to know whats the reason behind this.

Class1:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Class1 {
    private static boolean valid = true, accepted = false, exit = false;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        newThread t1 = new newThread();

        t1.start();
        do {
        try {
        int code = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
        if(code == 1010)
            accepted = true;
        else
            System.out.println("Please try again!");
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Please try again!");
        }
        }while(!exit);
        }
    public static boolean getValid() {
        return valid;
    }
    public static void setValid(boolean input) {
        valid = input;
    }
    public static boolean getAccepted() {
        return accepted;
    }
    public static void setAccepted(boolean input) {
        accepted = input;
    }

}
```

newThread:

```
public class newThread extends Thread{
    public void run() {

    do {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(Class1.getAccepted())
            Class1.setValid(false);
    }while(Class1.getValid());
    System.out.println("Code accepted");
    }
}
```

Expected without `Thread.sleep(1);`:

```
1010

Code accepted
```

Actual results:

```
1010
```

Comment: Your code isn't thread safe. Your booleans need to be `volatile`, at least. And the thread's infinite loop without a sleep is pretty selfish. The thread is actually completely pointless. You could put that code inline after the console input.

Comment: Threads need to `volatile`, synchronization, or locks to cooperate with each other.  See [the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3).

Comment: @user207421 I know, this code was me just trying out how threads work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without sleep the newThread consumes all cpu and has no natural break point. In the
[Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-17.html) you can read more about it.

Comment: to be more precise, it doesn't consume all CPU, it consumes the CPU share for the given JVM process